# Hard drive has no GBT/MBR, data usable in Ubuntu, shows as RAW in Windows, what can I do?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, gpt

A NAS broke down. Two identical ext4 seagate 8TB drives have been extracted from it, and put into a functional dual-boot Windows 10 /Ubuntu 16 computer.

The disks are in perfect working condition, but appear to have been partitioned, and/or formatted differently, so that only one of them is usable under Windows 10, using Ext2FSd, while both are read/write-able under Ubuntu.

The problematic disk shows as "RAW" under Windows.

Under Ubuntu, using for example fdisk, the fully working disk shows

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 7.3 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 59C72E14-A30C-4858-8FE5-F2E6298FAB1D
```

while the problem disk shows

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 7.3 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

I suppose it has been formatted without first choosing a partitioning scheme. Am I correct in that regard... and how do I (pun ^^) correct that, so that Windows will read it, without losing its data?

Thanks for your time and interest! :)

Comment: "I suppose it has been formatted without first choosing a partitioning scheme." - Based on the Linux output, the disk is GPT, you can't have a file system without either being GPT or MBR.  In this case, you created an EXT2 partition, on a GPT disk.  The obvious problem is an incompatibility with Windows 10 and Ext2FSd.  You failed to provide some vital information.  What version of Windows 10 are you running?  Use **winver** to provide this vital required information by editing your question.

Comment: I am not sure of that, the *working* disk shows "disklabel type : gpt"
The problematic one does not show the same fields, even though it is the exact same make of hard drive.
Furthermore one of the two disks does what it is supposed to using the Ext2Fsd driver, so I don't see what obvious incompatibility there is between that driver and win10.

Comment: My guess is the second disk is unpartitionef and Linux is reading the whole disk as a single large partition while Windows does not handle this. Im not at all certain it can be fixed without copying, repartitioning, restoring or doing some dangerous block level hacks to effectively do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simpliest way to get out of this is just **cloning the functional drive to the broken one**, since there is no way to change the partition format from RAW to NTFS (or anything else) while keeping all the data intact.

**EDIT**
Try to boot ubuntu and see if the problematic disk shows up. You can easily change everything using gparted, to be fully comptible with Windows 10. Saves some time.

Comment: gparted will let me add a partition scheme, but warns me in bold characters that all data will be lost. I'm editing the question to indicate that both disks do what they are supposed to under 'buntu, and one of the disk only, under win.